# Boltzmann distribution as an explanation for the 2nd law of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

The [Wikipedia page for Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution) describes it as a distribution of microstates as a function of energy and temperature. From my understanding, the 2nd law of thermodynamics is based on the idea that there are a greater proportion of microstates for some given macrostate (in a combinatorial sense), and this macrostate is thus what is most likely.

Is there an intuitive way to directly use the concept of Boltzmann distribution to explain the 2nd law (i.e. the H-theorem)?

Comment: The H-theorem is not equivalent to the 2nd law of thermodynamics, so using i.e. above is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

The Boltzmann distribution is the equilibrium distribution of a system in contact with a thermal reservoir. It is therefore derived assuming maximum entropy of the joint system+reservoir. Obviously, the second law cannot be derived from this distribution.

In order to ‘derive’ the second law, one requires some form of kinetic theory that describes how the system, which is not in equilibrium with the reservoir initially, equilibrates over time. The Boltzmann equation can describe such a process in specific cases.

Comment: Second law of thermodynamics is not about systems approaching equilibrium in time. What you're probably thinking of is the so-called zeroth/minus first law of thermodynamics: given sufficient time, any isolated system approaches some equilibrium state. https://www.physik.uni-augsburg.de/theo1/hanggi/Minus.pdf

Comment: @JánLalinský: Thanks for your comment, I agree with your statement that the second law is not about systems approaching equilibrium in time. This is, why I put the word `derive' in quotation marks. However, I felt that Tejas Ramdas was hoping for an intuitive way to gain insight into the second law. In my opinion, this is what kinetic theories can provide to some extent making them a great didactic tool.

Comment: @JánLalinský: take N particles in a box, where everything is elastic (particles and walls). What's the "equilibrium" according to this "-1 law"?  On the other hand, in hydrodynamics (where you are close to local thermodynamic equilibrium), entropy is the Lyapunov function of the dynamical system that drives it at equilibrium: in this case "the 2nd law is about systems approaching complete equilibrium".

Comment: @Quillo thermodynamic equilibrium state is supposed to be a unique special state which does not change in time. I don't think entropy in hydrodynamics or dynamical systems are directive for the formulation of 2nd law of thermodynamics (they may be relevant for "derivation" of 2nd law of thermodynamics, but that is a difficult subject). Entropy there is very different concept from Clausius entropy.

Comment: @JánLalinský: coming back to your first comment. The way I understand the second law is that it gives a direction to thermodynamic processes in which a system changes (in time) from one state to another. Isn't the "arrow of time" a concept that is directly related to the second law?

Comment: @flaudemus Time in physics is unproblematic already in newtonian mechanics, it is measured by controlled periodic processes such as mechanical clocks. The concept has no interesting connection to 2nd law or entropy or thermodynamics. The concept of time and its measurement is fine even if 2nd law is violated, which we know happens on small spatiotemporal scales (fluctuations). Thus I don't see a reason to attach an "arrow of time" to the concept of time and seek connections to 2nd law. Time moves on even when a system keeps in equilibrium state and its entropy is constant.

Comment: @JánLalinský: I agree with your notion of measuring time in Newtonian mechanics. However, the concept of the "arrow of time" is not attached to the concept of time in classical mechanics, but directly to the second law. The basic idea is that even in macroscopic thermodynamics, there is a direction of time evolution (without a scale), because nature evolves irreversibly from states of higher entropy to states of lower entropy. This concept was introduced in the early 20th century by astronomer Arthur Eddington, and is still used today in thermodynamic measurements.

Comment: @JánLalinský: I agree that "time moves on even when a system stays in equilibrium and its entropy is constant", but only at the microscopic level (time-evolution of microstates). However, at the macroscopic thermodynamic level, there is no time evolution any more, and in this sense, there is no way to see time evolving in the equilibrium state.

Comment: @flaudemus It does not matter that we can't detect time progress using just sequence of changing thermodynamic states (say, entropy) of an thermodynamic system; time still moves on. Such measurement strategy is a bad clock in general, because it does not have discernible discrete states equidistant in time. Even in a system in state of thermodynamic equilibrium, fluctuations and microscopic motions still continue, so time hasn't stopped.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why you think Boltzmann's probability distribution should play a role in derivation of 2nd law. 2nd law states something about possible values of macroscopic constraints like $V,T$ at the end of processes that begin and end at some equilibrium state. Boltzmann's distribution depends on such variables as $V,T$, but does not place any constraint on them. So the relation is more likely the opposite: from the 2nd law of thermodynamics, or some equivalent (maximum information entropy for isolated system), one can derive the Boltzmann distribution.

If you want to derive 2nd law, this can be done in several ways, but one has to assume some equivalent of it. For example, there is the method of information entropy, introduced to thermodynamics by E.T. Jaynes. In this method, one assumes that thermodynamic entropy is maximum possible information entropy. See my answer here:

[Understanding Gibbs $H$-theorem: where does Jaynes' "blurring" argument come from?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256302/understanding-gibbs-h-theorem-where-does-jaynes-blurring-argument-come-fro/256472#256472)