# Weinberg's proof of Gibbs' $H$-theorem

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, stochastic-processes, arrow-of-time

I'm trying to understand Weinberg's explanation of a general $H$-theorem he attributes to Gibbs ([Foundations of Modern Physics, p. 35](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=VvQgEAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA35#v=onepage&q&f=false)), but I'm having trouble with the mathematical modeling.

The goal is to show that the negative Gibbs-entropy $\int{P(\alpha)d\alpha\ln{P(\alpha)}}$ doesn't increase in time. In the proof Weinberg assumes that there is a "differential rate $\Gamma(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$ such that the rate at which a system in state $\alpha$ makes a transition to a state within a range $d\beta$ around state $\beta$ is $\Gamma(\alpha \rightarrow \beta) d\beta$." I thought that $\Gamma(\alpha \rightarrow \cdot)$ is the conditional probability density function of moving to some other state immediately after being in $\alpha$; my problem is that this leads to me to expect that the probability of being at state $\alpha$ at time $t$ should satisfy
$$\frac{dP(\alpha)}{dt} = \int{d\beta P(\beta) \Gamma(\beta \rightarrow \alpha)},$$
in analogy to discrete Markov chains. However, Weinberg writes that
$$\frac{dP(\alpha)}{dt} = \int{d\beta [P(\beta) \Gamma(\beta \rightarrow \alpha) - P(\alpha) \Gamma(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)]},$$
the intuitive explanation being that the probability of being at $\alpha$ decreases if the system transitions away from $\alpha$, hence the additional term.

How can Weinberg's equation be justified? Is this an assumption with physical insight, or a result in probability about certain kinds of stochastic systems? If the latter, what kinds of stochastic systems are these?

Finally, the statement of the theorem seems to contradict results that the Gibbs entropy remains constant due to Liouville's theorem (e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256302/understanding-gibbs-h-theorem-where-does-jaynes-blurring-argument-come-fro)). Surely there is some thing that Weinberg assumes or does differently, but I don't know what.

Comment: "How can Weinberg's equation be justified?" Because you don't just transition *into* the state $\alpha$, you also transition *out of* the state $\alpha$.

Comment: This irreversible kinetic model of probabilites can be consistent with Hamiltonian evolution of the individual system, if the probabilities in the model are those of some large regions of phase space or set of microstates. One can get the irreversible model from the reversible one by coarse-graining. E.g. the reversible model is about positions and momenta of particles, and the irreversible one is about probabilities of states of *cells* in the phase space.

Comment: Indeed this kind of model of evolution does not manifest Liouvillian conservation of probability density/density matrix and thus conservation of the associated Gibbs entropy of such probability distribution. The Liouville conservation is property of Hamiltonian evolution, classical or quantum. The master equation for probabilities is not such kind of model. It is an irreversible kinetic model; "velocities" (derivatives of probabilities wrt time) are already determined by "coordinates" (probabilities), so reversing velocities is not possible. It is not possible to reverse the evolution.

Comment: @JánLalinský Thanks! Is it not possible to encode in a master-equation model (over the phase space of positions and momenta) probability 1 of transitioning according to the trajectory that solves the Hamiltonian? Is this a problem of continuity, or something else?

Comment: The only way to preserve all information about an Hamiltonian system in a dynamical model is to use Hamiltonian evolution, i.e. Hamilton's equations and canonical variables, or the Liouville equation and probability distribution $\rho$. These models are reversible. Master equation is less informational: either number of degrees is lower, or the description is only approximate. The master equation is not reversible, one cannot change initial conditions and make the system retrace the past. Master equation is an entirely different kind of model from reversible dynamics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Weinberg's equation is actually called "the master equation" in the context of non-equilibrium statistical mechanics. Just to complement @RogerVadim's answer, the master equation for Markov chains (discrete time and space) can be rewritten in a way that seems more similar to the equation you are asking about.

$$P(\alpha,k+1)-P(\alpha,k)=\sum_\beta W(\beta\to\alpha)P(\beta,k).$$
Where the $W$'s are transition probabilities that have to be normalized, therefore:
$$W(\alpha\to\alpha)=1-\sum_{\beta\ne \alpha} W(\alpha\to\beta).$$
Inserting this in the first equation:
$$P(\alpha,k+1)-P(\alpha,k)=\sum_{\beta\ne \alpha}[ W(\beta\to\alpha)P(\beta,k)-W(\alpha\to\beta)P(\alpha,k)].$$
If time is continuous, you can rewrite the above equation in terms of transition rates (your $\Gamma$'s):
$$\partial_tP(\alpha,t)=\sum_{\beta\ne \alpha}[ \Gamma(\beta\to\alpha)P(\beta,t)-\Gamma(\alpha\to\beta)P(\alpha,t) ].$$
If states are continuous:
$$\partial_tP(\alpha,t)=\int d\beta[ \Gamma(\beta\to\alpha)P(\beta,t)-\Gamma(\alpha\to\beta)P(\alpha,t) ].$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Following your answer, I searched for something that derives the continuous version, and [these notes](https://www.itp.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/a3233/upload/AG_Schoell/Hizanidis/mastermanu_01.pdf) seem helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Weinberg's equation seems easier to justify then the preceding equation in the OP. Indeed, suppose the system can be found in state $\alpha$ with probability $P(\alpha, t)$, in state $\beta$ with probability $P(\beta, t)$ and so on - this statement is redundant, since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are just indices that run over *all* states, but I want to distinguish two arbitrarily chosen states. At time $t+\Delta t$ we expect that, if the system were in state $\alpha$, it may transition to state $\beta$ with probability $P(\beta,t+\Delta t|\alpha, t)=\Gamma(\alpha\rightarrow\beta)\Delta t$. On the other hand, if the system were in state $\beta$, it may transition to state $\alpha$ with probability $P(\alpha,t+\Delta t|\beta, t)=\Gamma(\beta\rightarrow\alpha)\Delta t$. Thus, the change of probability to be in state $\alpha$ due to these two types of transitions is
$$
P(\alpha, t+\Delta t)- P(\alpha, t) =
P(\alpha,t+\Delta t|\beta, t)P(\beta, t) - P(\beta,t+\Delta t|\alpha, t)P(\alpha,t)
$$
(same can be written for state \beta, but I remind that $\alpha,\beta$ are just indices.)
If we account for all the states, we write
$$
P(\alpha, t+\Delta t)- P(\alpha, t) =
\sum_{\beta\neq \alpha} P(\alpha,t+\Delta t|\beta, t)P(\beta, t) - 
\sum_{\beta\neq \alpha} P(\beta,t+\Delta t|\alpha, t)P(\alpha,t)
$$
(I write sums rather than integrals in order not to bother with the integration measure.)

More formally it could be cast as Smolukhovsky equation:
$$
P(\alpha, t+\Delta t)= \sum_{\beta\neq \alpha} P(\alpha,t+\Delta t|\beta, t)P(\beta, t) + \left[1
- 
\sum_{\beta\neq \alpha} P(\beta,t+\Delta t|\alpha, t)\right]P(\alpha,t)=
\sum_\beta P(\alpha,t+\Delta t|\beta, t)P(\beta, t),
$$
where
$$
P(\alpha,t+\Delta t|\alpha, t)= 1
- 
\sum_{\beta\neq \alpha} P(\beta,t+\Delta t|\alpha, t)$$
is the probability that the system remains in state $\alpha$, which is the same as the probability that it does not leave from $\alpha$ to any other state. Indeed, this equation is just  a restatement of normalization
$$
1= 
\sum_{\beta} P(\beta,t+\Delta t|\alpha, t),$$
that is, regardless of the state at time $t$, the probability of finding the system in any of its states at $t+\Delta t$ is $1$.

*Alternative view:*
One could start with the equation in the OP
$$
\frac{dP(\alpha)}{dt}=\int d\beta P(\beta)\Gamma(\beta\rightarrow\alpha)
$$
and integrate it over $\alpha$. Since $\int d\alpha P(\alpha)=1$, we would have
$$
0=\int d\beta P(\beta)\int d\alpha\Gamma(\beta\rightarrow\alpha).
$$
Since the transition rates are defined as positive, it would mean that the $P(\beta)=0$ for any state $\beta$, which violates the normalization.

**Remark:** The whole exercise can be viewed as shuffling money between multiple bank accounts - the money leaving one account must end in the other accounts, but the total remains the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to wrap my head around this from a rigorous perspective. Could you comment on the difference between this and [master equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_equation) (except the state space being discrete), which seem to use an equation similar to what I proposed? 
Also if you have a reference to which equation called Smolukhovsky's you're referring, I'm not sure I found the correct one?
Thanks again.

Comment: @YotamFeldman what I call Smoluchovsky equation is also known as [Chapman-Kolmogorov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapman%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_equation). I think *Master equation* is just a term used in physics and chemistry for [Kolmogorov forward equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_equations_(continuous-time_Markov_chains)) for discrete states. You could probably gain from reading something on Markov processes (unfortunately, I cannot suggest anything, as I studied those things long time ago and it was in Russian.)