# Can one derive the second law of thermodynamics from von Neumann's equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, arrow-of-time

My idea is that from the von Neumann equation
i$\hbar\dot{\rho}(t) = [H,\rho (t)]$
one can derive that
$\dot{\sigma}(t)\geq 0$,
where $\sigma(t):= -$tr $ \rho(t) $ log $\rho(t)$. However, I end up at
i$\hbar \dot{\sigma}(t) = -$tr $[H, \rho(0)]$ log $\rho(0)$.
I am confused about my result as it would mean that $\sigma$ is an affine function. However, by now I would have heard of the fact, that any increase in entropy is linear in time.
Also, in a Hilbert space of dimension $d\in\mathbb{N^+}$ entropy is bounded from above by log $d$ from which one can conclude that $\dot{\sigma}(t)=0$. I suspect that most often (even in infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces) one can further simplify my result to $\dot{\sigma}(t)=0$. This is horrible from a physics point of view.

So why is it that the von Neumann equation produces these results? Should one not be able to derive the laws of thermodynamics from quantum mechanics? If not, what is then the point of statistical mechanics? Even worse, should quantum mechanics and thermodynamics not produce consistent results? If they do not, why is no one worried about this?

Comment: See Jaynes' Brandeis lecture notes. There, he derives it under additional assumptions (which you always need). In particular, he assumes a macroscopic reproducible process and the postulate that the maximal information entropy is (in equilibrium) the thermodynamic entropy. See also [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256302/understanding-gibbs-h-theorem-where-does-jaynes-blurring-argument-come-fro)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to derive the second law of thermodynamics from the von Neumann equation without additional assumptions. As far as I know, the von Neumann equation is an equivalent of the equations of unitary evolution of quantum mechanics and does not contain any irreversibility.

Answer (score 1):

To see an increase in entropy from the evolution of a state you would have to trace over equivalent micro states. The Lindblad equation would be a better starting point. Otherwise you would see a constant entropy. At the fundamental level information is conserved.

The equation that you end up with actually evaluates to zero, because $\rho(0)\log[\rho(0)]=\log[\rho(0)]\rho(0)$ so that the trace of your commutator evaluates to zero.